# why does this simple strcpy(...) cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, strcpy

I'm not understanding something simple.

I have this sample code:

```
typedef struct {
  char* fname;
} PersonType;

int main() {
  PersonType *p;
  p  = (PersonType *)malloc(sizeof(PersonType));
  char * name = "Robert";

  /* this next line causes a segmentation fault */  
  strcpy(p->fname, name);

  printf("name: %s\n", p->fname);

}
```

Why is there a segmentation fault at the 'strcpy'?  What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciate, thanks!

Rob

Comment: You need to allocate space for fname; your malloc only allocates space for the pointer itself.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for fname as well. Allocating memory for PersonType alone is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PersonType` struct contains a pointer to a string that you are never allocating, nor assigning.  So `fname` is an uninitialized pointer that you are attempting to write to.  You need to allocate a buffer for `fname`.

```
int main() {
   PersonType *p;
   p  = (PersonType *)malloc(sizeof(PersonType));
   p->fname = malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
   char * name = "Robert";
```

Either that or make `fname` a `char` array so that your struct will contain a buffer within itself.

Answer (score 3):

Although you allocated space for the structure, you've neither allocated space for the string nor initialized the pointer in the structure.  You need to use something like:

```
if (p != 0)
{
    if ((p->fname = malloc(strlen(name) + 1)) != 0)
        strcpy(p->fname, name);
    else
        free(p);  // Report error too?
}
```

Note that this checks the results of the memory allocation.  I'm not fussed about whether you cast the return type for `malloc()`; other people are.

Answer (score 0):

`fname` is not initialized to anything. `strcpy` will continue to read starting at the location `fname` points to until it encounters `\0`.

Either make `fname` an array, and initialize it. Or allocate fname and initialize it.